# Find nth occurence of groups of thousands which sum to a given number in lexical order

Tags: math, numbers, partition

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322715/find-groups-of-thousands-which-sum-to-a-given-number-in-lexical-order) asked for the solutions in lexical order (lowest to highest) to

> a+b+c+d… = x
>
> where a,b,c,d… is an arbitrary number of integers between 0-999 and x
>   is a fixed integer

An answer was given which fully computes this efficiently using python.

However, for very large numbers, the loop could take years to complete.

For example, the huge number:

`304,153,525,784,175,759`

is a solution for `x=2700` since the groups of threes add up to `2700`

`304+153+525+784+175+759 = 2700`

However, to loop through the algorithm to get the n<sup>th</sup> solution which equals this number would take months or years.

Is there a way to calculate the n<sup>th</sup> solution directly? I.e. for a known solution, to calculate how many solutions are less than this one.

Comment: What is the 1st solution ?  What is the rule for going from the `n`-th solution to the `n+1`-th ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark not sure. there is an algorithm for looping through in the linked question. not sure how to break that down into a single formula

Comment: This is a non-trivial problem in enumerative combinatorics. You are essentially asking for an `unrank` function which goes from a rank (index) to the combinatorial object at that rank. [mathematics.se] might be a better place to ask.

Comment: @JohnColeman tried there. but they dont know. its a non mathematical manipulation so could be johanC's solution is the best one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to find the index of a solution (or: how many smaller solutions there are). The code has two parts:

- Find how many solutions there are for some fixed number `n` of groups for a given sum `x`. This is a recursive function. Basically, for `n` groups and sum `x`, for all k from 0 to 999, sum up how many solutions there are with `n-1` groups and sum `x-k`. As the recursive function often is called with the same values, the results are stored in a memoization dictionary to be used immediately the next time.
- Use this function to calculate how many smaller solutions there exist. This is a similar way of summing. E.g. for 6 groups and starting with `304`, calculate how many 5-groups there are which start after `303` and sum to `x-303`, add the number of 5-groups which start with `302` and sum to `x-302`, etc.  Then, taking `304,153` as start, find how many 4-groups start after `304,152` and sum to `x-304-152`, etc.

Here is the complete code, tested for quite some inputs (test generated by the previous program). It just takes a few seconds for the given 18-digit number.

```py
grouping = 3
max_in_group = 10 ** grouping - 1
number_to_test = 304153525784175759  # number_to_test = '304,153,525,784,175,759'
d = {}  # dictionary for memoization

# count how many solutions there are for n groups summing to x, and each group being a number from 0 to max_in_group;
# when counting simple digit sums, n is the number of digits, and max_in_group should be 9;
# when counting in groups of thousands, n is the number of groups (digits / 3), and max_in_group should be 999
def count_digitsums(x, n, max_in_group=9):
    if not(0 <= x <= n * max_in_group):
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        if (x,n) in d:
            return d[(x,n)]
        s = 0
        for i in range(max_in_group+1):
            s += count_digitsums(x-i, n-1, max_in_group)
        d[(x, n)] = s
        return s


def find_index_of_number(number_to_test):
    global max_in_group
    a = []
    while number_to_test != 0:
        a.append(number_to_test % (max_in_group + 1))
        number_to_test //= max_in_group + 1
    print("number to test:", ",".join(f'{i:03d}' for i in a[::-1]))
    print("numbers should sum to:", sum(a))

    x = sum(a)  # all the solutions need this sum
    leftx = 0  # the sum of the numbers to the left of the group being processed
    s = 0
    for k in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
        for l in range(a[k]):
            # e.g. when 6 groups and a[5] = 304, first take 303, count number in 5 groups which sum to x-303
            s += count_digitsums(x - leftx - l, k, max_in_group)
        leftx += a[k]
    print("number of smaller solutions:", s)
    print("index of this solution:", s + 1)
    return s + 1


d = {}
find_index_of_number(number_to_test)
```

Output:

```
number to test: 304,153,525,784,175,759
numbers should sum to: 2700
number of smaller solutions: 180232548167366
index of this solution: 180232548167367
```

Comment: "numbers should sum to: 2700" - is there a way to change this number?

Comment: It is just the sum of the threes of the input.  Otherwise, you can't give an index to the input number. If you replace `x = sum(a)` by another value, the function still correctly counts the number of solutions smaller than the input.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: *this post only addresses how to find the next solution, given a particular solution.*

*OP asks additionally:*

- *Given an index `n` find the `n`<sup>th</sup> solution without the need to generate all the earlier ones.*
- *Given a solution `a`, find out how many smaller solutions there exist.*

As the algorithm efficiently finds the next solution, you just need to fill in your current solution.

Here is a way to fill in the current solution either as a large integer or as a string:

```
start = 304153525784175759  # start = '304,153,525,784,175,759'
x = 2700
grouping = 3
max_in_group = 10**grouping - 1

if start is not None:
    if isinstance(start, str):
        a = [int(s) for s in start.split(',')[::-1]]
    else: # suppose start is a large integer
        a = []
        while start != 0:
            a.append(start % (max_in_group+1))
            start //= max_in_group+1
else: # no start value given, start with the smallest
    a = [x]
```

If you prepend this to the rest of the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322715/find-groups-of-thousands-which-sum-to-a-given-number-in-lexical-order/59327920#59327920), you'll get the output:

```
304,153,525,784,175,759
304,153,525,784,176,758
304,153,525,784,177,757
304,153,525,784,178,756
304,153,525,784,179,755
304,153,525,784,180,754
304,153,525,784,181,753
304,153,525,784,182,752
304,153,525,784,183,751
304,153,525,784,184,750
304,153,525,784,185,749
304,153,525,784,186,748
...
```

Comment: does this give what number solution it is? ie is this the 25000th solution from lowest to highest?

Comment: No, finding exactly how many earlier solutions there are, is a trickier problem. As well as, given the index, find out which solution corresponds to it.  Maybe there is a recursive formulation?

Comment: yes indeed. current loop takes months+ or even years to complete for large values

Comment: thanks. i'm asking primarily "Given a solution a, find out how many smaller solutions there exist"

Comment: ok thanks. thought maybe a computer algorithm is the only way

Comment: You're talking real huge numbers. For `x=2700`, the 100millionth term is "only": `557,836,852,455`. The slowest part is printing out the numbers, so best only print the interesting ones. The 25000th term is `925,799,976`.

Comment: i'm trying to print out only the match and also once every billion numbers along the way. but even that is too slow