# Split a list into n randomly sized chunks

Tags: python, list, numpy, sublist, numpy-random

I am trying to split a list into n sublists where the size of each sublist is random (with at least one entry; assume `P>I`). I used numpy.split function which works fine but does not satisfy my randomness condition. You may ask which distribution the randomness should follow. I think, it should not matter. I checked several posts which were not equivalent to my post as they were trying to split with almost equally sized chunks. If duplicate, let me know. Here is my approach:

```
import numpy as np

P = 10
I = 5
mylist = range(1, P + 1)
[list(x) for x in np.split(np.array(mylist), I)]
```

This approach collapses when `P` is not divisible by `I`. Further, it creates equal sized chunks, not probabilistically sized chunks. Another constraint: I do not want to use the package `random` but I am fine with `numpy`. Don't ask me why; I wish I had a logical response for it.

Based on the answer provided by the mad scientist, this is the code I tried:

```
P = 10
I = 5

data = np.arange(P) + 1
indices = np.arange(1, P)
np.random.shuffle(indices)
indices = indices[:I - 1]
result = np.split(data, indices)
result
```

Output:

```
[array([1, 2]),
 array([3, 4, 5, 6]),
 array([], dtype=int32),
 array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
 array([10])]
```

Comment: Why do you insist on everything being a list if you're ok with numpy?

Comment: Do you mean I should be okay with arrays?

Comment: This seems like a [Stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)); divide P stars into I bins where each bin gets at least one element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General bars and stars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965734/general-bars-and-stars)

Comment: @Chris I tried the function Kevin provided in there. But, I could not see any relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) is still the way to go. If you pass in a sequence of integers, `split` will treat them as cut points. Generating random cut points is easy. You can do something like

```
P = 10
I = 5

data = np.arange(P) + 1
indices = np.random.randint(P, size=I - 1)
```

You want `I - 1` cut points to get `I` chunks. The indices need to be sorted, and duplicates need to be removed.  [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) does both for you. You may end up with fewer than `I` chunks this way:

```
result = np.split(data, indices)
```

If you absolutely need to have `I` numbers, choose without resampling. That can be implemented for example via [`np.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html):

```
indices = np.arange(1, P)
np.random.shuffle(indices)
indices = indices[:I - 1]
indices.sort()
```

Comment: You can try `P=11` and see that np.split does not work.

Comment: Further, np.split does not ensure len of each sublist (or sub -array) to be random/ Adversely, it creates equally len sub-arrays. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I did have a typo. The second argument should have been `indices`, not `I`. Fixed now. The behavior of `split` is very dependent on the second argument.

Comment: `np.choice` is better suited for that task despite `np.shuffle` would also work.

Comment: @GZ0. I'm on a mobile platform, and that's the first thing that came to mind. You're absolutely right thought, it's much better suited.

Comment: I updated my post. I still could not get what I want to have. I see some indices twice in different sub-arrays and some empty sub-arrays. @GZ0 how would you implement np.choice? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @user8028576. You're right, I forgot to sort the indices. They must be increasing monotonically. Fixed

Comment: I think this is happening because you are on mobile platform and cannot see the outputs.

Comment: There you go! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user8028576. I think you're right. Glad you finally got it working. I suggest you spend some time reading through the links I put in the answer and understanding exactly *why* it works.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be refactored as choosing `I-1` random split points from `{1,2,...,P-1}`, which can be viewed using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Therefore, it can be implemented as follows:

```
import numpy as np

split_points = np.random.choice(P - 2, I - 1, replace=False) + 1
split_points.sort()
result = np.split(data, split_points)
```

Comment: I'm glad you added this example.