# Sampling a fixed length sequence from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a data matrix `a` and I have list of indices stored in array `idx`. I would like to get 10-length data starting at each of the indices defined by `idx` . Right now I use a `for` loop to achieve this. But it is extremely slow as I have to do this data fetch about 1000 times in an iteration. Below is a minimum working example.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random(1000)
idx = np.array([1, 5, 89, 54])

# I want "data" array to have np.array([a[1:11], a[5:15], a[89:99], a[54:64]])
# I use for loop below but it is slow
data = []

for id in idx:
    data.append(a[id:id+10])  
data = np.array(data)
```

Is there anyway to speed up this process? Thanks.

**EDIT**: My question is different from the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915609/split-a-list-into-n-randomly-sized-chunks). In the question, the size of the chunks is random in contrast to fixed chunk size in my question. Other differences exist. I do not have to use up the entire array `a` and an element can occur in more than one chunk. My question does not necessarily "split" the array.

Comment: I am assuming `a` is *ones* for the purpose of the question, is that right?

Comment: @Ivan haha yes. I have edited it to now have random values.

Comment: this is trickier, because there are overlapping sections! If you do `np.split(a, idx)` you will split the array on indices `1`, `5` leaving you with `[array of size 1, array of size 4, ...` which is not the desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Thanks to suggestion from @MadPhysicist)

This should work:

```
a[idx.reshape(-1, 1) + np.arange(10)]
```

**Output:**
Shape `(L,10)`, where `L` is the length of `idx`

**Notes:**

1. This does not check for index-out-of-bound situations. I suppose it's easy to first ensure that `idx` doesn't contain such values.
2. Using `np.take(a, idx.reshape(-1, 1) + np.arange(10), mode='wrap')` is an alternative, that will handle out-of-bounds indices by wrapping them around `a`. Passing `mode='clip'` instead of `mode='wrap'` would clip the excessive indices to the last index of `a`. But then, `np.take()` would probably have a completely different perf. characteristic / scaling characteristic.

Comment: I'm thinking that it might be faster to sort the index, especially for short arrays. +1 either way

Comment: Also, you really don't need to reshape and transpose. The output array is the shape of the index. `idx.reshape(-1, 1) + np.arange(10)` is sufficient

Comment: @MadPhysicist -- Thanks, edited with the simplification.

Comment: We can see edits in the edit history. No need to mark "edit" and "update" in questions and answers. It's a common misconception among beginning authors that people want to see anything besides your polished product.