# Algorithm for generating 'balls in bins' outcomes with limits on bin size?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, combinatorics

Suppose we have N balls and M bins to put them into. The number of outcomes for this can be found using 'stars and bars' method [Integer Equations - Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/). We can also compute all the actual outcomes using the `itertools` package and get unique outcomes by using `sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations`.

If we restrict bin size however to some arbitrary number on [0, N], how could you efficiently compute all the possible outcomes? Is there a better way than computing all outcomes without bin size and then eliminating invalid outcomes afterwards?

For N = 2 and M = 3, the outcomes are `{200, 110, 020, 011, 101, 002}`.

For example, with N = 3 and M = 3, the outcomes are `{300, 210, 120, 021, 012, 030, 201, 102, 003, 111}`. But what if we wanted some array `b=[3,3,0]` specifying max bin size so that the only valid outcomes were `{300, 210, 120, 030}`?

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969798/10306224

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive approach placing 0 to maximum balls on the first bin and recursing with the remaining balls on the rest of the bins:

```
def ballPlacing(N,B):
    if N <= 0: return int(N==0)
    if len(B) == 1:
        return int(N<=B[0])
    total = 0
    for c in range(min(N,B[0])+1):
        total += ballPlacing(N-c,B[1:])
    return total

print(ballPlacing(3,[3,3,3])) # 10
print(ballPlacing(3,[3,3,0])) # 4
```